# the app crash all the time with a video player

Tags: ios

I am trying to put a video code in Xcode I am using storyboard but every time that crash me this is the error :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:

I connect the button to the `IBAction` but after I press the button the app crash me

```
- (IBAction)playMove;
{
    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"skill" ofType:@"flv"];    


    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
    theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(64, 100, 200, 150);
    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];

    [theMovie play];
}
```

my file is `name.mp4` large 480* 360 but thats it crashed  this is the code

```
- (IBAction)playMove;
{
    NSURL *url =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"go" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
    player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [player.moviePlayer play];

}
```

and the button are connect fine what can i do to fix it ?

I am trying to use without storyboard and with story board but always crashed.

This is the error:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e0a022 0x1348cd6 0x1db2a48 0x1db29b9 0xb9753b 0xb974c5 0x21dc 0x1e0be99 0x25814e 0x2580e6 0x2feade 0x2fefa7 0x2fe266 0x27d3c0 0x27d5e6 0x263d
```

Answer (score 1):

its because you are trying to play FLV file by `MPMoviePlayer`.

this is from the apple api documentation for MPMoviePlayerController supported formats:

**Supported Formats**
This class plays any movie or audio file supported in iOS. This includes both streamed content and fixed-length files. For movie files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:

H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)
If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, this class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio.

Comment: Well, apart from you being entirely correct on FLV not being iOS compliant - that crash certainly has a different reason. The reason is that the given string is `nil`.

Comment: my file is name.mp4 large 480* 360 but thats it crashed  this is the code
- (IBAction)playMove;
{
    NSURL *url =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"go" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
    player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [player.moviePlayer play];
    player =nil;
}


and the button are connect what i can did ?

Comment: ok so what i need to do this is the code - (IBAction)playMove;
{
    NSURL *url =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];

    [player.moviePlayer play];
} this is the error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'